# Excel: How to automatically format cells in Column B with the format of identical cells (values) in Column A?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns (A & B) of part numbers. Column A has parts that are highlighted in multiple colors. Column B doesn't have any highlighted parts. If any one cell in Column B contains an identical part number to one in Column A, I would like to format that cell with the same color.

Example:

[image]

In this example I manually highlighted the cells in Column B to show what I'm hoping to be able to do automatically.

I have been manually highlighting Column B, but that is very time consuming. The actual file is a couple thousand lines long. I would like to use some sort of formula so I don't have to spend the time doing it manually.

Note: The cells in Column B that are highlighted in red are unique values and are already done when I start the process. Also, I can ignore the white cells.

Comment: how are the parts highlighted in column A are they manually done or by conditional formatting?

Comment: As there are many different numbers that both in column A and B, if you need to use different color to hightlight them, I am afraid you need the code to help. If you can use one color to hightlight them, you can use conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, perhaps easiest with VBA coding - yet there is another way without coding:

1. There is an old Excel 4.0 macro function called GET.CELL which you can only call from a named range, which can return information about a cell such as its fill colour.
2. So, you can use MATCH to find the first matching value in column A (lets call this *data*), then `INDEX(data, MATCH(data, B2, 0))` to return a reference to the matching cell, then `GET.CELL(63, INDEX(...MATCH(...)))` to return the fill colour of the matching cell AND do all of this as a named range, lets call it *matchbg*.
3. Now define conditional formatting with "Use a formula..." and put say `=matchbg=3` for matching to standard red, and select standard red as the CF fill colour.
4. Add additional CF rules for each fill colour number used (see *tip* below).
5. On changes, hit SHIFT+F9 to force recalculate all the CF rules.

To define the named range, **put your cursor in B2**, hit CTRL+F3 > New, give the name *matchbg* and set "Refers to:" to

```
=GET.CELL(63, INDEX(data, MATCH(B2, data,0)))
```

NB: Save the file as macro-enabled .xlsm or otherwise the GET.CELL macro function won't work.

Tip: Define another name *getbg* as `=GET.CELL(63,$A$1)` and use it to determine the fill color numbers (e.g. 3 for red, 6 for yellow) of cell A1.